# How do I animate a cabinet with two doors that swing open and closed

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, .fbx, unreal-engine

I am learning Blender in order to animate BluePrints in UE 4.  My first attempt is a cabinet that has two doors that open outward (think side by side refrigerator or two door cabinet).  My model has 3 main objects, the base cabinet, a left door and a right door.  Each of the doors has it's own hinge.  I've built the CAD model, and imported everything correctly into Blender.

I give each of the doors it's own origin (to use as the door swing axis), and all that is working fine.  My goal is to have a single BluePrint in UE 4, that has two animations:  1) Open (both) doors, and 2) Close (both) doors.  Then I can use the BluePrint multiple times and give each instance a command to open or close and I'm on my way.  I tried to do this all in UE 4, but the animations got really weird with the second door, so I turned to Blender.

I have rigged armatures in several different ways, but am struggling to find the best way to come out with the single cabinet object with the two animations described above.  After multiple attempts, I have gotten to the point where I can export the entire hierarchical object with two armatures, an open animation for the left door, and an open animation for the right door, but it's still not what I want.

I tried rigging with a single armature with connected bones, and having the two door objects (with their meshes) parented to the two "arm" bones that swing out and in, but had problems.  I might have done it wrong (should I have used disconnected bones with a single armature?.

I switched to having two different single bone armatures, one for each door.  Each bone has an origin at the hinge of that door.  I parented each of the door meshes to the appropriate single bone armature, and can animate each door open swing.  In the dope sheet, I keyframed each of the armatures on a single timeline.  The animation works the way I want in Blender, with both doors swinging open simultaneously.

I export the fbx, and examine it in FBX Review (freebie from Autodesk), prior to import into UE 4.
I get multiple separate animations, but there is a good one one for the right door and one for the left door.  I import into UE 4 and get similar results.

How to I simplify this workflow so that I can have a single animation that causes both doors to swing open simultaneously?  Once I get the two door animation working, How would create a second animation where the doors start open, and swing close.

I would like to have one fbx file, a hierarchy of meshes (cabinet with two child doors) and two animations (one that opens doors, and one that closes doors).

I want to learn the right way to rig and animate simple mechanical devices in Blender.  I want to create animated objects that I can use easily drop into UE 4 to create Actors (I'm assuming with some Blueprint code) for building larger worlds (picture a factory floor with animated autonomous guided vehicles that move around, and have lifts that go up and down).

I might be close, but I'm banging my head against the wall getting this done.  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: When you export to UE4 can you retain the relationship between parent and child? (CTL-P)  If so and you animate the doors using local axis', would those keyframes export out and be accepted by UE4?  I ask this thinking it might work around the bone export problem.  Use a master parent instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I figured out my immediate problem.  What I needed to do was have a single Armature, and then just separate the bones, then keyframe an open sequence, and a close sequence, and put them into NLA strips.

So now my export from Blender is working.  My problem now is how on the UE4 side, triggering each as part of a montage.